# "Leider gibt es auf keinem keinen..." Ist das richtig geschrieben?

Tags: word-usage, dative, accusative

Wenn ich es richtig argumentiere, können der Dativ und der Akkusativ nebeneinander liegen und eins dem anderen folgen. Hier ist mein Abendsrätsel:

Es gibt hundert Exemplare eines CD-Releases. Theoretisch können auf einigen Exemplare die originale Sticker aufgeklebt werden. Ich habe alle Exemplare durchgesehen und keine Sticker darauf gefunden. Darf ich meinen Satz wie folgt formulieren?

> Leider gibt es **auf keinem** [Exemplar] **keinen** Sticker darauf.

Das Wort "Exemplar" (in eckigen Klammern) möchte ich in dem Satz nicht benutzen.
Das ist aber im Kontext gemeint. So stellt sich heraus: auf keinem keinen.

Können diese zwei Wörter zusammen stehen?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Leider gibt es auf keinem [Exemplar] **keinen** Sticker.

means that there is no exemplar without a sticker on it. So it is actually the opposite of what you want to express.

The correct way of saying there is no exemplar with a sticker on it is:

> Leider gibt es auf keinem [Exemplar] **einen** Sticker.

If what you are referring to is clear from the context, you can leave the word "Exemplar" out:

> Leider gibt es auf **keinem einen** Sticker.

---

> Leider gibt es auf keinem [Exemplar] **keinen** Sticker.

ist gleichbedeutend mit "Leider gibt es kein Exemplar, auf dem kein Sticker ist." Somit ist das genau das Gegenteil von dem, was du eigentlich ausdrücken möchtest.

Es müsste also

> Leider gibt es auf keinem [Exemplar] **einen** Sticker.

heißen, wenn du sagen möchtest, dass es kein Exemplar gibt, auf dem sich ein Sticker befindet.

Wenn sich aus dem Kontext ergibt, was gemeint ist, kannst du das Wort "Exemplar" natürlich weglassen und sagen:

> Leider gibt es auf **keinem einen** Sticker.

Answer (score 2):

> Leider gibt es auf keinem [Exemplar] keinen Sticker darauf.
>
> Können diese zwei Wörter zusammen stehen?

Ja, können sie.

Ich würde allerdings stattdesssen eine Formulierung mit "ohne" verwenden:

> Es gibt kein Exemplar ohne Sticker.
>
> Es gibt kein(e)s ohne Sticker.

oder das ganze positiv ausdrücken:

> Es gibt auf jedem (Exemplar) einen Sticker
>
> Jedes (Exemplar) hat einen Sticker (drauf).

Dann wird auch offensichtlicher (siehe Antwort von @fragezeichen), dass dein Satz nicht das aussagt, was du davor beschreibst.

Answer (score 0):

Kann es sein, fragezeichen, dass dir da was entglitten ist?

**Es gibt** Katzen und Hunde, Bäume und Sträucher, Dicke und Dünne und allerlei anderes auf dieser Welt - aber auf der CD **IST** ein Sticker. Oder keiner. Je nachdem.

@Interface Unknown, der Satz, den du suchst, lautet:

> Leider ist auf keiner CD einer drauf.

oder, wenn's denn unbedingt sein soll:

> Leider ist auf keiner einer drauf.

Was aber unter Umständen für Gelächter sorgen kann. ;-)

Comment: Danke für die Erklärung :)

Comment: Ich finde diese Antwort verwirrend. Was willst du mit den ersten zwei Absätzen sagen? Außerdem finde ich es verwirrend, dass du "Exemplar" durch "CD" ersetzt.

Comment: @Cheers, willkommen bei German. Stackexchange! Du bist ja noch ziemlich neu hier und das ist leider schon zweite Post von dir über den ich stolper. Ich würde dich daher bitten unsere Tour zu machen https://german.stackexchange.com/tour und einen Blick in den Help Desk zu werfen https://german.stackexchange.com/help mit unserem Code of Conduct, Expected Behavior und How do I write a good answer?